# How to correctly recalculate the height of the block when resize?

Tags: javascript

There are drop-down menus in which nested drop-down menus. To make the appearance animation I calculate the height of each block at load time, write it to the block attribute and hide the block. When resizing I try to do the same

```
function activeHeight() {
    let allAccordion = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');

    allAccordion.forEach((item) => {
      let accordionParent = item.querySelectorAll('.accordion-parent');
      let accordionItem = item.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item');

      accordionItem.forEach((item) => {
        item.nextElementSibling.style.height = 'auto';
        item.nextElementSibling.dataset.height = item.nextElementSibling.offsetHeight;
        item.nextElementSibling.style.height = '0';
      });

      accordionItem.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.classList.contains('active')) {
          let element = item.closest('.accordion-parent');
          if (element?.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item.active')) {
            const allElement = element.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item.active');

            allElement.forEach((item) => {
              let innerElement = item.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item.active');

              let countInnerElement = +item.nextElementSibling.dataset.height;

              innerElement.forEach((element) => {
                countInnerElement += +element.nextElementSibling.dataset.height;
              });

              item.nextElementSibling.style.height = countInnerElement + 'px';
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

But the height begins to be calculated in different ways.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLMcp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRRxl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xquNl.png)

Comment: Interesting... can you make a JSFiddle for us to work with?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to solve the problem with pure css. If you could provide your css code it would help.

Because at the moment it seems like your dropdown container is not responsive so that it doesn't resize automatically however it should do so. I think it's possible that way and doesn't require JS to solve it.

Unfortunately without the css code i cannot give you a direct solution with css.